# A problem in Logic

Tags: logic

If A,B and C are statements such that C is true only if exactly one of A and B is true.If C is
false then which of the following statement is true?

$1$.If A is false then B is false.

$2$.If A is true then B is false.

$3$.Both A and B are true.

$4$.Both A and C are false.

Comment: I think my answer is very wrong...you need to specify for me whether _"C is true only if exactly one of A and B is true._ means $C \leftrightarrow (A \vee B)$ or if it means $C \leftrightarrow (A \otimes B)$ or neither of those.

Comment: @Jared - $P$ only if $Q$ is : $P \rightarrow Q$ : see this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631586/difference-between-only-if-and-if-and-only-if). Thus, if the statement of the problem is correct, we have that it must be translated as : $C \rightarrow (A⊗B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
There are two cases if $C$ is false :
*First case* : $A$ true, $B$ true
*Second case* : $A$ false, $B$ false

C is called the XOR function.

I let you finish the exercise and check the answers.

**Solutions**
1 is

> true

2 is

> false

3 is

> false

4 is

> false

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of interpreting the given information correctly.

What we are given is that if $C$ is true, then exactly on of $A$ and $B$ is true.

Now, if $C$ is false, our hypothesis is not satisfied and we are not sure of anything about $A$ and $B$. Thus, $A$ and $B$ could be anything.

Do not get confused thinking that the given statement is saying that "if exactly one of $A$ and $B$ is true, then $C$ is true."

Answer (score 0):

OK, so assuming you mean an exclusive or (which I think is correct) *and* that $P$ only if $Q$ means $P \rightarrow Q$ (i.e. if $P$ then $Q$)...which is explained [here](http://www.wwnorton.com/college/phil/logic3/ch10/ponlyifq.htm), then you have:

\begin{align}
\left((A \wedge \neg B) \vee (\neg A \wedge B)\right) \rightarrow C =& \neg\left((A \wedge \neg B) \vee (\neg A \wedge B)\right) \vee C \\
= & \left(\neg(A \wedge \neg B) \wedge \neg(\neg A \wedge B)\right) \vee C\\
=& \left((\neg A \vee B) \wedge ( A \vee \neg B)\right) \vee C \\
=& \left((\neg A \wedge ( A \vee \neg B)) \vee (B \wedge ( A \vee \neg B))\right)\vee C \\
=& \left(((\neg A \wedge A) \vee (\neg A \wedge \neg B)) \vee ((B \wedge A) \vee (B \wedge \neg B))\right)\vee C \\
=& \left((\neg A \wedge \neg B) \vee (B \wedge A) \right)\vee C \\
\end{align}

I think that's about as far as we can go--either $C$ is true (regardless of $A$ and $B$'s values), both $A$ and $B$ are *false*, or both $A$ and $B$ are true (note that both of the last two conditions negate the **exclusive or** making the implication trivially true).

Assuming $C$ is false, then we are left with: $(\neg A \wedge \neg B) \vee (B \wedge A)$.  This means that whatever value $A$ has, then $B$ has and vice versa.  This makes the first statement true, the second statement definitively false, the third statement false (because $A$ and $B$ could *both* be false), and the fourth statement false (because $A$ could be true and $B$ could be true...and of course $C$ is false as this was our assumption).

...note that if we look at the case when $C$ is true, then all of these statements are trivially true (we don't need to check that case).