# Translation of sentence to logic formula

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, logic-translation

Here are four sentences:

> 1. If Jessy moves his truck, Irene will play her guitar
> 2. Irene will only move her car, if Jessy moves his garbage cans
> 3. It is not the case, that Jessy will move his carbage cans and not move his truck
> 4. If Jessy moves his garbage cans, Irene will move her car and play the guitar

Suppose:

- t = "Jessy moves his truck"
- g = "Irene will play her guitar"
- c = "Irene will move her car"
- gc = "Jessy moves his garbage cans"

I have translated the sentences as stated below:

> 1. $t \rightarrow g$
> 2. $gc \rightarrow c$
> 3. $\neg (gc \land \neg t)$
> 4. $t\rightarrow (c \land g) $

But I'm very unsure about the third sentence. Have I done this right?

Answer (score 1):

The third one is fine, but the second one is wrong.  It says ‘Irene will **only** move her car, if Jessy moves his garbage cans’, but your proposed translation, $gc\to c$, admits the possibility that Irene will move her car and Jessy will not move his garbage cans. I suggest you make a truth table for this sentence and try to extract the translation from the truth table.

Comment: *Fine !* - It's a recurrent issue in this site; see at least this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631586/difference-between-only-if-and-if-and-only-if). According to me : $A$ **only if** $B$ means $A→B$. Thus n°2 is : "Irene will only move her car, **only if** Jessy moves his garbage cans".

Comment: @Mauro I think we are in agreement.