# Clarification regarding construction of the truth table of a conditional in How to Prove It

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

My question pertains to [pages 44-46](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=lptwaMuAtBAC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&pg=PA44#v=onepage&q&f=false) of section 1.5 - The Conditional and Biconditional of *How to Prove It* by Velleman.

Construction of the truth table for $P \implies Q$ begins at the bottom of pg. 44. Velleman starts by pointing out that since $P \implies Q$ stands for the statement ***"if $P$ is true, then $Q$ is true"***, this statement is clearly false if $Q$ is false when $P$ is true. Similarly, this statement is clearly true in the case where both $P$ and $Q$ are true, so we have:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
P&Q&P\Rightarrow Q\\ \hline
F&F&?\\
F&T&?\\
T&F&F\\
T&T&T\\
\end{array}$$

This is clear to me, but I'm not sure I understand the gist of Velleman's explanation for lines 1 and 2 (emphasis added):

> To help us fill in the undetermined lines in this truth table, let’s
> look at an example. Consider the statement “If $x > 2$ then $x^2 > 4$,”
> which we could represent with the formula $P(x) \implies Q(x)$, where $P(x)$
> stands for the statement $x > 2$ and $Q(x)$ stands for $x^2 > 4$. Of course,
> the statements $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ contain $x$ as a free variable, and each
> will be true for some values of $x$ and false for others. **But surely, no
> matter what the value of $x$ is, we would say it is true that *if* $x > 2$
> then $x^2 > 4$, so the conditional statement $P(x) \implies Q(x)$ should be true.
> Thus, the truth table should be completed in such a way that no matter
> what value we plug in for $x$, this conditional statement comes out
> true.**

For the case where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are both  false:

> But now consider the case $x = 1$. Then $x < 2$ and $x^2 = 1 < 4$, so $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are both
> false, corresponding to line one in the truth table. We have tentatively
> placed a $T$ in this line of the truth table, and now we see that this
> tentative choice must be right. If we put an $F$ there, then the
> statement $P(x) \implies Q(x)$ would come out false in the case $x =
> > 1$, and we’ve already decided that it should be true for all values of
> $x$.

And, for the case where $P(x)$ is false and $Q(x)$ is true:

> Finally, consider the case $x = −5$. Then $x < 2$, so $P(x)$ is false,
> but $x^2 = 25 > 4$, so $Q(x)$ is true. Thus, in this case we find
> ourselves in the second line of the truth table, and once again, if
> the conditional statement $P(x) \implies Q(x)$ is to be true in this
> case, we must put a $T$ in this line.

So, we have:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
P&Q&P\Rightarrow Q\\ \hline
F&F&\textbf{T}\\
F&T&\textbf{T}\\
T&F&F\\
T&T&T\\
\end{array}$$

**Questions**

I'm able to follow this example, but I think I'm missing its gist. **By the text in bold in the first quote above, is Velleman saying that because the statement "if some number x is greater than 2, then its square is greater than 4" is a *fact*, it holds regardless of the value of x? But does it matter whether it is a fact?**

I then came across [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48164/51462), which quotes [Enderton's explanation](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA21#v=onepage&q&f=false) for lines 1 and 2 of the truth table:

> For example, we might translate the English sentence, ”If you're
> telling the truth then I'm a monkey's uncle,” by the formula $(V \implies M)$. We
> assign this formula the value $T$ whenever you are fibbing. In assigning
> the value $T$, we are certainly not assigning any causal connection
> between your veracity and any simian features of my nephews or nieces.
> The sentence in question is a conditional statement. It makes an
> assertion about my relatives provided a certain condition — that you
> are telling the truth — is met. Whenever that condition fails, the
> statement is vacuously true.
>
> Very roughly, we can think of a conditional formula $(p \implies q)$ as
> expressing a promise that if a certain condition is met (viz., that p
> is true), then $q$ is true. If the condition $p$ turns out not to be met,
> then the promise stands unbroken, regardless of $q$.

I like the characterisation of a conditional as a *promise*, and I think this is what Velleman is trying to convey as well, but I'm not sure. **Also, wouldn't this change the interpretation of the truth table?** The last column now tells us whether or not a *promise* is kept, as opposed to whether or not a *proposition* is true.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, if the proposition states that a promise is kept, then the truth table can be interpreted as the definition of a promise and a proposition as well.

Comment: It is not easy to "explain" it without using "if... then" itself, "when" and other similar. Start from the two uncontroversial lines of the TT and consider that if we put F in the other two what we get is "and", that we already have.

Comment: Thus, we can convey the difcerence saying that "if P, then Q" must mean thT we have to rule out the case where P holds without Q, and this is the very old explanation interms of Q being necessary for P. All other cases are T by stipulation.

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA, where can I read more about this explanation?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA also to clarify, does "true by stipulation" just mean that the implication is true by definition (i.e. because we "said so") in those cases? I haven't encountered this phrase before.

Comment: Check different possibilities for them: F/F and the result is AND; T/F is EQUIV. We are left with case F/T, but in this case we have again the "unpleasant" case that $\text F \to \text T$ is T.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617562/conditional-statements-only-if) as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631586/difference-between-only-if-and-if-and-only-if).

Answer (score 1):

If you dip your hand in magma, then your hand will get burnt.

This is certainly true if you do dip your hand in it. But you can still burn your hand by placing it in, say bonfire, which isn't magma. And the consequent is true though the antecedent is false.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48235/766223) is a good example why $F\implies F$ is $T$